# Play an external audio track instead on video's audio

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-video, html5-audio, web-audio-api

Is there a way to play an external audio track in sync with a video, assuming they are the same length? The idea is to simulate a change in audio track like you would in a movie when changing languages. It seems like there isn't a native way. Btw, this is meant for browsers, mainly firefox and chrome.

I am unsure if there is something that can be done with the audio context here or will I have to play a muted video and an audio tag while somehow making sure they are in sync?

Thanks!

Comment: hi, might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880878/multiple-audio-tracks-for-html5-video

Comment: Sounds like they are saying it could be done with audiocontext, but they aren't explaining how.

Comment: @ErIK [AudioTracks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/audioTracks) are not supported except in Safari browser. **(1)** You can try using MediaSource Extensions (MSE) API to play custom or mixed a/v content. **(2)** Instead of generic "audios" and "videos" try to stick one actual format (like have one **Fragmented MP4** video with multiple **MP3** audios) then it's easier to learn what must be extracted from the format (video frame vs audio frame)...

Comment: @ErIK Anyways if you want to try MSE then prepare your material (a/v file inputs) and then ask a new question when you can use it to play 1 video + 1 audio and just need advice about changing the audio part sent to the media decoder...

Answer (score 1):

There is an old and meanwhile deprecated API which was meant for doing exactly that. It's called `MediaController` and there is still an implementation in Safari today.

Assigning both media elements to the same controller should be enough to sync them with each other.

```
<video controller="audio-and-video" src="video.file"></video>
<audio controller="audio-and-video" src="audio.file"></audio>
```

There is a more flexible thing called a `TimingObject` that can be used as well. It's not implemented in any browser but can be implemented in pure JavaScript. Let's imagine the HTML is the same as above.

```
<video id="video" src="video.file"></video>
<audio id="audio" src="audio.file"></audio>
```

It's then possible to use a bit of JavaScript to sync both media elements to the same `TimingObject`.

```
import { TimingObject } from 'timing-object';
import { setTimingsrc } from 'timingsrc';

const videoElement = document.getElementsById('video');
const audioElement = document.getElementsById('audio');

const timingObject = new TimingObject();

setTimingsrc(videoElement, timingObject);
setTimingsrc(audioElement, timingObject);
```

Instead of calling `play()` and `pause()` on one of the media elements you would then control the playback by updating the `TimingObject`.

```
// play
timingObject.update({ velocity: 1 });

// pause
timingObject.update({ velocity: 0 });
```